# Where to find glass 'support' requirements?

Tags: roof, safety, materials, glass

Where could I go about finding the maximum safe span of a pane of glass for a specific width?

I.e. say you had two rafters, X meters apart, with glazing bars, supporting a pane of toughened glass (arbitrary height) 4mm thick along two edges; how would I go about finding, or finding the information to help me calculate, an appropriate maximum value of X?

(In order to determine whether a given design provides sufficient support.)

Comment: I'm confused - is the glass sheet lying flat?

Comment: @Doresoom, sorry no pane is on a 1/3 (33deg.) pitch roof.

Comment: Time to use [Mohr's Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr's_circle)! Do you know what type of tempered glass you're planning on using? Physical properties of the glass are going to play a big part in this. Also, what material are you using for glazing bars, and how will they be attached?

Comment: Except the real answer is whatever the building code requires - it doesn't usually have much to do with physics

Comment: @Doresoom - I contacted a supplier but they didn't have any technical information on the glass. The response I got implied that they recieved "standard" clear glass (they cut and toughen it) from a couple of suppliers. While I obviously don't think theres such a thing as standard glass it is more believeable that for many common small building projects (conservatories, etc), glass with similar properties is used. I know this isn't a very good question but was hoping that there was an equation, liked the one you linked, that I could use to get a couple of specific values to request from the...

Comment: ...large manufacturer my supplier referred me to. I'll read up on Mohrs Circle, thank you!
@mgb - my project is small enough that building control does not apply so the thought of using the regs as a reference went completely over my head, thank you! I will look them up now.

Answer (score 1):

You still have too many unknowns to make such a calculation, e.g.

- Wind load needs to be taken into account.
- Snow load needs to be taken into account.

The above loads will totally depend on whereabouts in the world you are installing said glass.

For total peace of mind (and most likely to cover yourself legally) you really should hire the services of a a qualified structural engineer to perform such calculations.

Rule of thumb, back of a cigarette packet calculations tend to only get people into trouble further down the road.

Comment: In the UK we have the BS 5516 which is the code of practice for design and installation of patent glazing (which is the edge supported glass roofing I was interested in). This includes maps and tables for determining things such as snow and wind loading, and example calculations for using these and other criteria for determining the load on the glass, and then selecting an appropriate thickness for the loads and span using the included graphs.
I knew someone who worked for a university who got me a copy from Athens (which provides access to things like this to different institutions)

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure how much use this will be to anyone else as without access through something like that a copy costs a couple hundred pounds!

Comment: @sebf, no offence to yourself or anyone else that might read this, but the average Joe on the street is not in the right position (have the necessary education/experience) to fully comprehend such a document and everything else that is associated with it. If an average Joe used said document to design a piece of glass and got it wrong (because they don't fully understand what is truly involved) the ramification could be very! damaging. That is why I fully stand by my initial answer/suggestion that a qualified structural engineer should be employed to perform such a professional task.

Comment: Its always tricky when answering questions like this, I know. Some of the 'average joes' I know couldn't design a dog house that stayed up overnight but others' capabilities far outweigh _some_ of the many professionals in the many trades I have dealt with.
I hope my response did not seem terse, I was simply stating there was an appropriate resource that could be used for the task; I don't intend to appear confrontational, but you don't know anything about me, or many others who may read this (I _really_ don't, but its very very hard to say that without sounding it :D)

Comment: The thing is, unlike UltimateHandyman or Diynot, the Q&A format of the Stackexchange sites doesn't lend itself well for indepth conversations, in which the provider of assistance can get to know and gauge the capabilities of the receiver over a long conversation. The whole site is designed to be about brief, fact based, generic questions and comprehensive but to the point answers, which leave us with a choice: answer a question and risk encouraging someone of suspect competance to do a job that may result in disaster later on, or respond with 'Call a pro'(TM).
I see why the first is scary,

Comment: but if every other question on here was answered with the latter, this site wouldn't exist for very long!
My thinking on this is three fold: a. If someone has managed to find their way here, and ask a question in such a way that it can be sensibly answered, they must have an idea of what they are doing. b. Despite overwhelming evidence to the contrary, I tend to think people aren't _that_ stupid, and although they may say "well im going to do it anyway!", when they acctually get to clearing the site, or pulling off the bumper,

Comment: or cutting their walls they will realise when a job really is over their head and stop (and if they don't they'll at least realise when they messed up and call a pro to fix it) c. (This one is a bit contentious!) Both our buildings and the creatures that inhabit them are alot more resilient than we give them credit for. The last time I was in Egypt the truck driver pulled over and proceeded to top up its brake fluid res. with tap water - you suggest that on here and half the members would have kittens! but I'm guessing he'd been doing it for years and will continue to do it for many more.

Comment: Someone bodges the electrics its 'dangerous', but theres a 99.999% chance that what happens is one or two safety devices 'up-wire' will operate and a pro will fix it (need proof? Check out DIYNOT and see how many people say 'I replaced my ceiling rose now whenever I turn on the switch it goes bang'). I have *never* heard of someone dieing as a direct result of poor DIY.
I can completely see where you are coming from, but I think sites like this are a very valuable resource, and knowledge should't be hidden because someone might hurt themselves with it.

Comment: (I also believe the number of comments it took to post that serves to prove my point about the format of this site vs. an actual forum! :D)

Comment: @sebf, my comment was not meant to cause offence (or be confrontational), nor was I taken aback by your comment. I was _only_ stating my personal opinion.

Comment: @sebf, "I have _never_ heard of someone dieing as a direct result of poor DIY.", then you are very! lucky. Please don't ask me to go into gory details here, I will ignore such requests.

Comment: I know you didn't, thats why I went into such (probably excrutiating ;)) detail, so you knew I acctually had real reasons behind my opinion and wasn't just being a reactionary jerk to you (hope that came across :D))